# How To Scan a Seven Segment Display by Firebase ML kit Text Recognition?

Tags: flutter, dart, ocr, firebase-mlkit, text-recognition

The Text Recognition API in Firebase Ml kit is not recognizing the digital numbers or a seven segment display numbers that i am trying to scan out from a weight scale , is there anyway to work it out ?

I tried the Dart package for firebase ml vision for flutter apps , and i used the firebaseVisionImage class and Text Recognizer class and visionText class as shown .

```
 // get image file
final File imageFile = File(widget.imagePath);

// create vision image from that file
final FirebaseVisionImage visionImage =
    FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(imageFile);

// create detector index
final TextRecognizer textRecognizer =
    FirebaseVision.instance.textRecognizer();

// find text in image
final VisionText visionText =
    await textRecognizer.processImage(visionImage);
```

I expected to have the numbers as an output but , it's not recognized at all ,

Answer (score 2):

If the ML Kit model doesn't automatically recognize the text in your image, there isn't a lot you can do to tweak it.

Instead you'll want to:

- Check if the Cloud Vision model is better able to extract the text from your image.
- Look into training a [custom model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/use-custom-models) for extracting your specific type of text.
- Look at other dedicated text extraction packages.

Answer (score -1):

You need to process the image in this type

```
 final inputImage = InputImage.fromFilePath(imageFile.path);
 final RecognizedText recognizedText = await textRecognizer.processImage(inputImage);
```

i hope it works :)